# At command doesn't run scripts with f key

Tags: at

I tried to schedule a task with `at` command using the following:

```
at now + 1 minute -f alarm.sh
```

It didin’t run a chosen script. Then I tried:

```
echo "./alarm.sh" | at now + 1 minute
```

It didn’t work either.

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04. I figured that the basic linux commands run well (e.g. `touch`). Although some GUI apps don’t. `Gnome-calculator` runs, `vlc` and `audacious` don’t. `Gnome-calculator` runs even if the error is there. I also tried using a way to open a file using `xdg-open`, presuming it would be a correct way to launch a GUI app. It didn’t work.

I’ll appreciate an advice on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what operating system you are using and ii) tell us if `atd` (the `at` daemon) is running; iii) show us the output of the commands you tried, did `at` print anything? iv) what happens if you pass it a working command like `echo "touch /tmp/atHasRun" | at now + 1 minute`? Is the file `/tmp/atHasRun` created? (your echo commands wouldn't work since they don't give a valid command to `at`).

Comment: Immediately after submitting the job, run `atq`. If it shows your job with a number (e.g. 170), run `atq -c 170`. This will show whether the job even got submitted, and then what commands it will execute. The first 50 or so lines reported just set up the environment -- your commands are the last lines in the file. Also note `at` probably starts in /bin/sh -- if you run a script with at, it must have a shebang. Finally, your original command is invalid -- all the options must precede the time specification.

Comment: is there a space between `+` and `1` or is this a copy typo ?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I figured that the basic linux commands run well (e.g. `touch`). Although some GUI apps don’t. `Gnome-calculator` runs, `vlc` and `audacious` don’t. Updated the qustion with this. Using `at -c jobnumber` I found an error 'Execution directory inaccessible'.

Comment: You didn't find that error `Execution directory inaccessible`. You found a code block (near the end of a sh script) that verifies that the directory where you invoked `at` is still available when it executes. It is conditional, wrapped by `cd /some/dir || { echo theMessage >&2; exit 1; }` and your actual job code (if present) starts immediately after that.

Comment: Launching GUI tools from the command-line is not straightforward. If I launch `xed`, it works fine from CLI, but `at` sends me email that it cannot connect to its server and has no DISPLAY variable set. `xdg-open xed` and `xdg-open /usr/bin/xed` both fail, but for two more different reasons. I never considered using `at` for GUI tasks, so my know-how here is exhausted.